# What does $(selector)[0] mean in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The syntax that I don't understand is this:

```
$("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0]
```

I have been seeing this syntax pretty frequently and I've ignored it for a while because I never had to use it. But now, in order to understand the code from this post [How do I upload an image using the Parse.com javascriptSDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279515/how-do-i-upload-an-image-using-the-parse-com-javascriptsdk), I cannot ignore it any longer.

I know that `[0]` this syntax is used to refer to an array usually. But it seems a little weird that a reference to an `id` would generate an array of some sort.

Comment: It accesses the DOM element directly, without the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: Next to that, this function is able to handle classes and IDs, and as such can result in either an array of elements, or one element. Because it is against every convention to have one function with multiple return types, it will always return an array as an array can also contain only one match.

Comment: [Closely related to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return)

Comment: In relation to your (now deleted) paragraph, we discourage members from deleting questions here that they have asked. A major point of Stack Overflow is to ask questions that other people can learn from. So, if you have a question that you wish to later delete, it cannot be asked here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By appending `[0]` to the jQuery object will return the **first** DOM element.

As you're using id selector here, there will be only one element in the array so using `[0]` makes sense. If you are selecting multiple elements you can also use any number which is between 0 and number of elements you can get corresponding DOM element.

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)

> A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM) elements that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a document. Since jQuery methods often use CSS selectors to match elements from a document, the set of elements in a jQuery object is often called a set of "matched elements" or "selected elements".
>
> The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a `length` property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their numeric indices `[0]` to `[length-1]`. Note that a jQuery object is not actually a Javascript Array object, so it does not have all the methods of a true Array object such as `join()`.

Comment: I see... so `[0]` is not representative of an array or anything like that.

Comment: Should say will return the ***first*** element in collection

Comment: @JaeKim: correct. Bracket notation can be used with  any object. All that does is accessing the property `0` of that object. Example: `({0: 42}[0])` returns 42.

Comment: @Jae, [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/) is used for the same. But that involves a function overhead, and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: @JaeKim Actually the `[0]` is representing the index position in the returned array. The jQuery function you're referring to returns an array containing all of the elements that match the given selector. In your case, this is an array of only one element. But if you're finding a class for example, the array will return with all matching items in that class. So e.g. `jQuery('.imapsMapPolygon')[4];` could be a valid element coming from the array.

Answer (score 11):

Well, don't confuse **[jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)** with **[DOM node/element](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614)**.

`this` should be as simple as

```
$(this)[0] === this
```

and

```
$("#target")[0] === document.getElementById("target");
```

e.g.

```
// Setting the inner HTML with jQuery.     
var target = document.getElementById("target");     

// Comparing DOM elements.
alert($(target)[0] === target); // alerts "true"

// Comparing DOM element and jQuery element
alert($(target)[0] === $(target).eq(0)); // alerts "false"
```

> We must keep in mind that both `$(target)[0]` and `$(target).get(0)`
>   return the same DOM element which has DOM properties like `.innerHTML`
>   and methods like `.appendChild()`, but not jQuery methods like
>   `.html()` or `.after()` whereas `$(target).eq(0)` returns a jQuery
>   object which has useful methods like `.html()` and `.after()`.

what's more

```
var logo1 = $("#logo");
var logo1Elem = logo1.get(0);

var logo2 = $("#logo");
var logo2Elem = $("#logo")[0];
```

Although `logo1` and `logo2` are created in the same way (and wrap the same DOM element), they are not the same object.

```
// Comparing jQuery objects. 
alert($("#logo") === $("#logo")); // alerts "false"

// Comparing DOM elements.     
alert(logo1Elem === logo2Elem); // alerts "true"
```

Ref: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery documentation the $() returns a collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) or created by passing an HTML string.  By adding the [0] you take the collection wrapper off the element and just return the actual DOM element when dealing with an id.  When dealing with a class you would return the element at the arrays position passed in through the bracket notation (in this case the first, since arrays are 0 based in JavaScript).

Answer (score -2):

In the case of an id selector, appending [0] to it has no sense because `$("#theIdOfTheElement")` will always return the first element.

Comment: wrong. Just because the standard says you cant have multiple elements with the same ID does not mean the browser will panic about it. In fact most browsers I know will allow such action and id selector could return multiple elements

Comment: jquery uses document.getElementById(id) (see : https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) that returns a reference to the element  (the first one in case you have multiple elements with the same id) (see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids