# How jQuery behaves differently when assigning an element to a variable compared to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I assign a jquery element to a variable, it won't match the element in a comparison, but when I assign a javascript element it will...

```
test1 =  $(".the_div");
console.log(test1 ==  $(".the_div"));
// logs false


test2 = $(".the_div")[0];
console.log(test2 == $(".the_div")[0]);
// logs true
```

What's going on? Why this happens?

Comment: Well, `test1[0] == test1[0]` would yield true as well…

Comment: Both collections contain the exact same element. Still, the two collections are two separate objects with their own identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test1` is an **Object**, and you cannot compare two objects using comparison operators. To compare two jQuery objects use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) as shown in [jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)

`test2` is a **String**. By appending `[0]` to the jQuery object will return the outerHTML of the first element in the set.

See [What does $(selector)[0] mean in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783869/what-does-selector0-mean-in-jquery)

Comment: `test2` is not a string.

Comment: Can you detail your first statement, please? `test1 == test1` is easily comparable (and even yields `true`).

Comment: @Bergi `test1` is jQuery Object so it cannot be compared using `==`. `test2` is string, `[0]` will return the outerHTML of the matched element, Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783869/what-does-selector0-mean-in-jquery/32783887#32783887)

Comment: Your [own answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32783887/1048572) says "*`[0]` […] will return the first DOM element*" - which is correct. DOM element, not outerHTML. It's an object, not a string.