# <input> range slider not resetting the color value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Slider before resetting is at this position: (both thumb and color are at proper position)

[image: Before slider reset]

**Before Reset:**

**Html**

```
<input id="xyzslider" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" value="0.0" step="0.05" tabindex="20">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#xyzslider").val(value);
```

**After Reset:**

Here is my problem. The slider thumb is reset to the minimum value but the color value represented by the slider is still at 0.6.

[image: Slider after reset]

After this i reset the slider in the following way.

**Jquery**

```
$("#xyzslider").val(minValue);
```

My code is below. What could be the issue here? Why is the slider color value not getting reset? Any help would be invaluable.

```js
$("#xyzslider").val(0.6);

$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $("#xyzslider").val(0.0);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

<br>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Click Me To Reset Slider">
<input id="xyzslider" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" value="0.0" step="0.05" tabindex="20">
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qahf2wuL/9/)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I [can't seem to reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/qahf2wuL/1/). Can you make a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate?

Comment: Provide css for your slider.

Comment: Hi @showdev i have updated the above jsfiddle which shows the problem. Link https://jsfiddle.net/qahf2wuL/9/

Comment: @Alex I have updated the above jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to description of mdl slider 
*"Although the value attribute is used to set a slider's initial value, it should not be used to modify the value programmatically; instead, use the MDL change() method. For example, assuming that slider1 is a slider object and newvalue is a variable containing the desired value, do not use slider1.value = newvalue; instead, use slider1.MaterialSlider.change(newvalue)"*

https://getmdl.io/components/#sliders-section

So update your code like

```
$("#xyzslider")[0].MaterialSlider.change(minValue);
```

Updated in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qahf2wuL/12/

Comment: Hi this does not work for me. I get the following error. "Cannot read property 'change' of undefined" i.e MaterialSlider is not defined. Where is the definition for "MaterialSlider"? How do i make Jquery know about it?

Comment: Your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qahf2wuL/13/) as per @AlexS pointed out.

Comment: Hi, why use $("#xyzslider")[0] instead of just $("#xyzslider") ?

Comment: MaterialSlider is not a module of jQuery, it used on DOM object directly

Comment: @SRINI794 See [What does $(selector)\[0\] mean in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783869/what-does-selector0-mean-in-jquery)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!