# Accessing table cells in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How come this works:

```
    alert(document.getElementById("tableId").rows[7].cells[7].innerHTML);
```

But not this:

```
    alert($("#tableId").rows[7].cells[7].innerHTML);
```

For context, I had used .append to add in cells to the table, and I want to be able to manipulate each cell further in the future (such as using .data, which is why I want to use jQuery.

Alternatively, are there other ways to access the individual cells in the table? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former works because `getElementById()` returns an HTMLTableElement object which has the `rows` property. The latter uses a jQuery object which does not have the `rows` property, so you get an error.

You could solve this by retrieving the underlying Element from the jQuery object in one of two ways:

```
console.log($("#tableId")[0].rows[7].cells[7].innerHTML); // access by index
console.log($("#tableId").get(0).rows[7].cells[7].innerHTML); // get(0)
```

Alternatively you could use jQuery selectors to select the cell you want directly:

```
let html = $('#tableId tr:eq(7) td:eq(7)').html();
```

> For context, I had used .append to add in cells to the table, and I want to be able to manipulate each cell further in the future

If this is the case you can save a reference to the content you add so that you can use it again without having to perform a DOM access operation. In pseudo-code it would look something like this:

```
let $content = $('<tr><td>Foo</td></tr').appendTo('#tableId');

// in some other function later in the page execution...
$content.find('td').text('bar').data('lorem', 'ipsum');
```

Comment: Could you explain why you put a [0] after $("#tableId")? What exactly is it accessing?

Comment: It's accessing the jQuery object and retrieving the original Element object from which it was created. [Here's a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32783869/519413)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to loop over each row

```
$('#tableId tr').each(function() {
  if (!this.rowIndex) return; // to skip first row if you have heading
    console.log(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
});
```